# android Media Player E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1015)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have shared a valid mp3 file in my google drive however I am not able to play it due to
 E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1015)
I cannot find any documentation for this error
my link :"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m_TKhtlPRBzBEencnU5-RITxheXm4x6q/view?usp=sharing"
my music service:

```
enter code here
```

package com.example.mpservice;

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;


public class PlayService extends Service implements
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
        ,MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        public final  String TAG="MyService";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
      Log.d(TAG,"playService start");
       mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

        //mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.summer);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate Finish");
        }
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");

    Log.d(TAG, "URL  :" + url);
   // Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.summer);
   // Uri myUri = Uri.parse(url);
    //Log.d(TAG ,"URI: " +myUri);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "data source" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"prepare  :" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
        }
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

        if(( mediaPlayer !=null)&& mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer=null;
            Log.d(TAG, "media player stoped " );
        }
         Log.d(TAG, "on Destroy " );

    Log.d(TAG, "media lpayer :"+mediaPlayer );
        super.onDestroy();

        }
@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        }
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        }
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
         Log.d(TAG, "error media player " + what +extra);
        return false;
        }
@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.d(TAG, "info media player " + what +extra);
        return false;
        }
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "mp start ");
    mp.start();
        }
@Override
public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        }
}
```